# How To Open Webpage without addressbar in android

Tags: android, browser

I use this code for open browser and open webpage with addressbar

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
Itent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

But I want hide addressbar in my webpage

Answer (score 0):

For this you can just use your WebView. Opening the default browser will always have an address bar.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to use a `WebView` with a `WebViewClient`. You open the system browser you can not hide the address bar

Comment: webview is ok for this,but i want use my webpage with remote control but webview can't work successfully with remote control(cannot select links,menus and etc)

Comment: I tested it but cannot selected,mozilla firefox,chrome browsers cannot successfuly work with remote control,I Use Q1 himeda settopbox

Comment: when you say remote controll you mean zoom and pinch ?

Comment: no no...i said top-down-left-right with keys and selected objects in my webpages

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use WebView Client. This will surely work.

```
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebView`:

```
WebView wt;

wt.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/"); 

// Make sure that to prevent opening in browser with address bar, 
// dont forget to add below line

wt.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic example uses `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

See: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Awesome app </title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
     <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="/icon.png">
   </head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

as for opening it you can click on a link placed on the homescreen. This link is done by clicking the "add to home" option. I hope to find a way to automate the creation of this link...